# Generate Random Popups from Marker Clusters on zoom out using Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have been working on developing a web app using Leaflet.js and Jquery. I am a beginner with javascript too.

I have built a map with custom markers and used marker clustering feature of leaflet.js to cluster all my data points in circles.

I have used the bindPopup() method to add text popups for my markers.  Here's the code which does the marker clustering and popup binding on mouseover. I am using lat-long coordinates from a GeoJson file which I had brought in using Jquery getJSON function.

Having got the data, I did this

```
var abc = L.geoJson(data,{
          pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
          var marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon: Icon});
     marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.City + '<br/>' +  feature.properties.Text);             

marker.on('mouseover', function(e){
marker.openPopup();

 });
    return marker;
  }
}).addTo(map);

var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
clusters.addLayer(abc);
map.addLayer(clusters);

});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to randomly generate some popups from within each  cluster when I zoom out! How do I achieve that?  Do I need to add a zoom out event handler inside the L.geoJson method?